# Переадресация

Tags: .htaccess, php, html

Допустим сайт example.ru 
мне нужен редирект на главную(example.ru) при переходе на example.ru/gif.gif

Answer (score 1):

Можно например в файле .htaccess написать

> `Redirect 301 /gif.gif http://example.ru`

А вообще [вот](http://sb-money.ru/article.php?a=75) почитайте.